# Internet Explorer won't load/play my custom IMFByteStreamHandler with new MIME type

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, ms-media-foundation

I'm doing this to understand how the Media Foundation works. So the "why" here is "because I want to learn".

I have a IMFByteStreamHandler for a custom media type (along with its associated source and stream objects). I have confirmed everything plays within Windows Media Player (so I know my basic pipeline is functional).

I copied the video file (with my custom file format) to my local IIS server, registered the new MIME type (video/ocv) with the server, and then created the following HTML page also on my localhost:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test page</title></head>
    <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="calibration.ocv" type="video/ocv">
    </video>
</html>
```

I made sure the MIME type was registered under the registry as per this documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for registering a byte stream handler).

Proof:

[image]

But nothing plays. At all. In fact, when using Process Explorer to watch the registry keys that are being queried, I see that IE doesn't even go LOOKING for my handler (I verified it does look in the registry for the byte stream handler by MIME type for MP4 files).

So what gives? Am I not able to use a custom media format in a  element even if it's registered? This is what I'm presented with (the top is my custom "OCV" file, the bottom is a standard MP4 file):

[image]

Thanks in advance. 
Ben

Comment: This is likely something Microsoft has to look at,as it deals with the inner workings of IE. Did you report this to them?

Comment: No, I haven't yet -- I was hoping I was doing something stupid somewhere. I'll try reaching out to my contacts there. 

I'll post any conclusions here.